# Computing weekly averages using Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, time-series, average, pivot-table

I have several time series for several years. Now I want to calculate the weekly average. But the problem is, that it needs to be the average from Wednesday to Wednesday. Here is a small data sample:

```
Date         X
03.01.2005  2.154
04.01.2005  2.151
05.01.2005  2.151
06.01.2005  2.15
07.01.2005  2.146
08.01.2005  2.146
09.01.2005  2.146
10.01.2005  2.146
11.01.2005  2.146
12.01.2005  2.145
13.01.2005  2.144
14.01.2005  2.144
15.01.2005  2.144
16.01.2005  2.144
17.01.2005  2.143
18.01.2005  2.144
19.01.2005  2.143
20.01.2005  2.144
21.01.2005  2.143
22.01.2005  2.143
23.01.2005  2.143
24.01.2005  2.143
```

So `05.01` is a Wednesday.

How can I calculate the average for example from and with `06.01` to and with `12.01` (i.e. always 7 days)?

For this example it would be:

(2.15+2.146+2.146+2.146+2.146+2.146+2.145)/7=2.146429.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Grouping in a PivotTable. `Date` for ROWS (not text format) and Average of `X` for VALUES. Then select a date in the PT and Group, Starting at: `06/01/2005`, Days (only), Number of days: `7`.

[image: SO29661310 example]

Comment: Nice, that is even easier!

Answer (score 0):

You can put week numbers (modified for Wed-Tue) in a helper column like this:

```
=IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=12,WEEKNUM(A2-3)=53),53,IF(WEEKNUM(A2-3)=53,1,WEEKNUM(A2-3)))
```

With the results in the helper column you can then use formulas like

```
=AVERAGEIF(C:C,1,B:B)
```

Where 1 is the week number you want the average for. Or better yet, throw the results into a pivot table to have it give you the averages for every week number.